# Как правильнее (лучше) создавать модели данных при программировании

Tags: java, mvc

Допустим есть таблицы в БД с именами, назовем ее nameclients, которая имеет поля nameclient_id, nameclient_name и nameclient_country. И есть таблица country которая имеет поля country_id и country_name. Поля nameclient_country и  country_id связаны через внешний ключ.
Дальше становится задача создать, скажем на java модель (проекцию) этой структуры. И тут возможны два варианта. С классом справочником Country все легко

```
class Country{
   int id;
   String name;
}
```

а вот с классом NameClient интереснее, первый вариант:

```
class NameClient{
   int id;
   String name;
   int country;
 }
```

или второй вариант

```
class nameclient{
   int id;
   String name;
   Country country;
 }
```

ну и собственно если начать брать более сложные случаи когда клиент приписан к разным странам.тогда в бд появляется промежуточная таблица,
а в классе nameclient надо создавать массив либо id значений либо массив экземпляр классов country.
причем посколько я использую Java то во втором варианте накладные расходы по идее ровно такие же. посколько в поле country хранится не сам объект а ссылка на уже созданные объект.
Я тут вижу и плюсы и минусы у обоих вариантов, а вот какой правильный не знаю. С одной стороны когда модель сложная, то разворачивать второй вариант проще чем первый, с другой стороны модель созданная в программе  сильно отличается от структуры базы данных. и вот это меня смущает...

Comment: Модель должна стремиться моделировать предметную область, а не базу данных (конечно если бд сама не является предметной область, что крайне редко). Из этих соображений правильный второй вариант.

Comment: Второй вариант правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения удобства второй вариант лучше - не надо делать лишние обращения к БД за странами по айдишникам.

С точки зрения общепринятости - в тех ORM что я видел используется второй вариант, ибо см. п.1

С точки зрения производительности - т.к. обращения к БД делать надо асинхронно, то, в общем, нет разницы сколько они продлятся, если в итоге будет удобнее, если все объекты будут сразу под рукой

Если же планируются гиганстские объёмы данных то тогда, пожалуй, первый вариант - ибо не надо будет тянуть сразу всё. Но это редкий случай и когда вы с этим столкнётесь вы уже будете знать что делать